# Draw map of roads between cities with kruskal algorithm

Tags: java

We have `class City { int num;
      Double x;
      Double y;
      };
     Road {
     Int num;
     City City1;
     City City1;
     Double distance};
     Arraylist<Road> Rsystem=new Arraylist<Road>();
     Rsystem(add(new Road(1; City1; City2);`

```
 `Rsystem(add(new Road(n; Citym; Cityk);`
```

But I need it to sort the arraylist of Roads in Ascending order, so beginning from the shortest;

So I want to ask could I apply such constructor of Roads as

```
 `Road {
 Int num;
 City City1;
 City City1;
 Double}  Road (int num, City City1, City City2) { this.num=num;
 this.City1=City1;this.City2=City2;this.distance=
 sqw((Pow(City1.x-  City2.x),2)+ ((Pow(City1.y-City2.y), 2);)`
```

Or should I use some method – `double getdistance(Road RoadN) { double d;
     d=((Pow(RoadN.City1.x-RoadN.City2.x), 2)+ 
     ((Pow(RoadN.City1.y- RoadN.City2.y), 2);

     Return d;}`

So then I use interface comparable (just one comparation) and want to
Sort such arraylist that include 
    `1. City1.City2.
     2. City2.City3.
     3. City1.City3`…
Should I include obligatory the field distance
    `1. City1.City2.500
     2. City2.City3.300
     3. City1.City3.550`…
to sort by it, or I can use just `getDistance(Cityn)`  to sort by it in Compare to `(Cityn.getDistance())`? What would you suggest?
And another question is could I just 
When it is sorted it could be viewed as
     `34.City32.City34
     22.city25.city27
     27.city28.city29`.

Can I sort just the index(number field of the objects of Arraylist that they should be viwed as
`1.City32.City34
     2.city25.city27
     3.city28.city29`.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor in Road set distance, to variable **distance**.

```
Arraylist<Road> Rsystem=new Arraylist<Road>();
Rsystem(add(new Road(1; City1; City2);
```

This is right.

So, if u need sort Collection of Road (Rsystem), you need to sort according **Double distance**.

Class road:

```
class Road {
     Int num;
     City City1;
     City City1;
     private Double distance;
     public Double getDistance(){
       return distance;
     };
};
```

You need custom comparator to sort according attribute:

```
public class RoadComparator implements Comparator<Road> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Road o1, Road o2) {

        return o1.getDistance() - o2.getDistance();
    }   

}
```

Then sorting is done by:

```
Collections.sort(Rsystem, new RoadComparator());
```

In this way, you can sort with any criteria.